# How to post data using crossdomain ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am using login webservices to validate the user.

These are spring 3.0 rest webservices designed in such a way that it accept only data with POST method.

I am able to send data to the webservices using GET.

But due to the webservices implementation I have to submit data using POST method.

If i use jquery ajax request with POST I am getting 403 Access forbidden error.

Below is the working example for GET request.

I am using CORS filter for tomcat to enable CORS support.

```
 function callservice() 
    {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var mobNo = document.getElementById('mobileNo').value;
        var acctNo = document.getElementById('accountNo').value;
        var custNo = document.getElementById('customerId').value;

        url = url+mobNo+"/"+acctNo+"/"+custNo;

        $.getJSON(url,
        function(data) 
        {
            if (data.authenticated==true)
            {
                alert("data "+data);
            } 
        });

}
```

But if i use following code i am getting 403 error.

```
    function callservice() 
    {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var mobNo = "123123123";
        var acctNo = "123123123";
        var custNo = "123123123";

        var url = "http://localhost/mobile-services/rest/user/";        
        var dataVal = {};
        dataVal["mobileNo"] = mobNo;
        dataVal["accountNo"] = acctNo;
        dataVal["customerId"] = custNo;

        var forminput = JSON.stringify(dataVal);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data:forminput,
        datatype:"jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function () { },
        headers : 
        {
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
            "Accept" : "application/json",
            "Origin" : "http://localhost/",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
        },
        success: function (data) 
        {          
            if (data.authenticated==true)
            {
                window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/selected_services.jsp?userId="+data.id);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            try 
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest) + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            }
            catch (ex) { alert("Exception occured.. "); }
            finally { }
        }
    });
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Does this help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could try YQL to make cross domain requests.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Comment: YQL allows us to make cross-domain GET requests.I want to use POST.